# SSRS 2017 report loading very slowly

Tags: reporting-services

I have a very simple report that is taking a very long time to run.  The query is a simple tablescan of 25 records in a select * from table statement as the datasource.  The query runs in milliseconds in ssms and the execution plan is very straight forward.  I am using no parameters in the report.

However, after deploying the report to the server, the loading screen can take up to 30 seconds to show the report.  I checked the execution log and the rendering time is low, so I am wondering if there is a setting or something I am missing that could speed this up.  The report design consists of several text boxes and each record is one page.

The only thing I can think of is that issue with SSRS where, if you haven't run a report for awhile it can take a long time the first time you run it (recycle time).  It's almost as if it's trying to run for the first time EVERY time.  So any suggestions I can get would be most welcome.

Comment: So you not gonna show us the query? Or describe what elements the reports has? Or shows the actual numbers from the execution time stats? Is the report server on the same host as the database?

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler when running the report to check if it actually does the same query you think it is doing, or if it does any others (maybe in the [Advanced -> Code] section of the report which can run custom code)

Comment: I apologize for the lack of code, but the server is on a network which does not have internet access.    I will copy down the execution stats and post them here shortly.  The report server is on the same host as the database.  SQL Profiler shows it is running the same query I am expecting, in this case `select * from testtable`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was rooted in the fact the server does NOT have internet access.  Since MS automatically opts you into their CEIP program to send feedback and error reports, the reporting server was trying to do that and that caused the long load times.  I opened the Error Usage and Reporting setting the the start menu, unchecked all the boxes and presto, super responsive and fast report.